# Can you smart-search on Google, keywords within URL's instead of body text

Tags: search

I was wondering if one could smart search with Google, looking for URL's containing your keywords, instead of searching for websites containing your keywords, on the page themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inurl:, intext:, inanchor:, and intitle: search filters, e.g., by using one these queries in the search box

Pages with Obama in the URL; the phrase, climate change, in the title; & talk about solar power or education

```
inurl:obama intitle:"climate change" intext:("solar power" education)
```

Pages containing Obama in the URL and not Michelle, that talk about the State of the Union address

```
inurl:obama -inurl:michelle ("SOTU" | "state of the union")
```

Government sites using WordPress

```
inurl:wp-content site:.gov
```

The allinurl:, allintext:, allinanchor:, and allintitle: search filters also exist & supersede other filters, e.g.,

```
allintitle:barack michelle obama
```

is equivalent to:

```
intitle:barack intitle:michelle intitle:obama
```

or more simply:

```
intitle:(barack michelle obama)
```

however you can't search for:

```
allintitle:barack michelle obama -inurl:-divorce intext:"climate change"
```

wherease you can search for:

```
intitle:(barack michelle obama) -inurl:-divorce intext:"climate change" 2008..2016
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, yes.  Googles advanced search (http://www.google.ca/advanced_search) will allow you to search the URL.  In the **terms appearing:** drop down select **in the URL of the Page** and it should do what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I didn't knew there was an advanced search! ~ Or I forgot/overlooked :)